# StdClass Object return only one value

Tags: php

Hy, I just stuck in Array Object.
I am receiving course list in array object from foreach value. 
This is value.

```
Course List
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 4
    [category] => 24
    [sortorder] => 10004
    [fullname] => test-course-2
    [shortname] => test-course-3
    [idnumber] => 
    [summary] => <p>Testing Course 2</p>
    [summaryformat] => 1
    [format] => singleactivity
    [showgrades] => 0
    [newsitems] => 0
    [startdate] => 0
    [enddate] => 0
    [marker] => 0
    [maxbytes] => 0
    [legacyfiles] => 0
    [showreports] => 0
    [visible] => 1
    [visibleold] => 1
    [groupmode] => 0
    [groupmodeforce] => 0
    [defaultgroupingid] => 0
    [lang] => 
    [calendartype] => 
    [theme] => 
    [timecreated] => 1536066556
    [timemodified] => 1536066556
    [requested] => 0
    [enablecompletion] => 1
    [completionnotify] => 0
    [cacherev] => 1547443283
)
Course List
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 3
    [category] => 24
    [sortorder] => 10005
    [fullname] => test-course-2
    [shortname] => test-course-2
    [idnumber] => 
    [summary] => <p>Testing Course 2</p>
    [summaryformat] => 1
    [format] => singleactivity
    [showgrades] => 0
    [newsitems] => 0
    [startdate] => 0
    [enddate] => 0
    [marker] => 0
    [maxbytes] => 0
    [legacyfiles] => 0
    [showreports] => 0
    [visible] => 1
    [visibleold] => 1
    [groupmode] => 0
    [groupmodeforce] => 0
    [defaultgroupingid] => 0
    [lang] => 
    [calendartype] => 
    [theme] => 
    [timecreated] => 1536066548
    [timemodified] => 1536066548
    [requested] => 0
    [enablecompletion] => 1
    [completionnotify] => 0
    [cacherev] => 1547443283
)
Course List
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 2
    [category] => 24
    [sortorder] => 10006
    [fullname] => test-course-1
    [shortname] => test-course-1
    [idnumber] => 
    [summary] => <p>Testing&nbsp;</p>
    [summaryformat] => 1
    [format] => singleactivity
    [showgrades] => 0
    [newsitems] => 0
    [startdate] => 0
    [enddate] => 0
    [marker] => 0
    [maxbytes] => 0
    [legacyfiles] => 0
    [showreports] => 0
    [visible] => 1
    [visibleold] => 1
    [groupmode] => 0
    [groupmodeforce] => 0
    [defaultgroupingid] => 0
    [lang] => 
    [calendartype] => 
    [theme] => 
    [timecreated] => 1536066531
    [timemodified] => 1536066531
    [requested] => 0
    [enablecompletion] => 1
    [completionnotify] => 0
    [cacherev] => 1547443283
)
course Receving
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 2
    [category] => 24
    [sortorder] => 10006
    [fullname] => test-course-1
    [shortname] => test-course-1
    [idnumber] => 
    [summary] => <p>Testing&nbsp;</p>
    [summaryformat] => 1
    [format] => singleactivity
    [showgrades] => 0
    [newsitems] => 0
    [startdate] => 0
    [enddate] => 0
    [marker] => 0
    [maxbytes] => 0
    [legacyfiles] => 0
    [showreports] => 0
    [visible] => 1
    [visibleold] => 1
    [groupmode] => 0
    [groupmodeforce] => 0
    [defaultgroupingid] => 0
    [lang] => 
    [calendartype] => 
    [theme] => 
    [timecreated] => 1536066531
    [timemodified] => 1536066531
    [requested] => 0
    [enablecompletion] => 1
    [completionnotify] => 0
    [cacherev] => 1547443283
)
```

In last, I am getting only one value outside of foreach value.

What I want:

I want to concatenate all [fullname] value in stdclass object. Like this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [fullname] => test-course-2,test-course-2,test-course-1
)
```

Code Using:

```
private function get_course($course) {
    global $DB;

    /***************** CUSTOM *****************/
    //print_object($course);
    $enrolledusercourses = enrol_get_users_courses($this->user->id); 
    // print_object($enrolledusercourses);
    $cour = array();

    foreach($enrolledusercourses as $key =>$value){ 
        $course = $enrolledusercourses[$key]->id;

        /***************** CUSTOM *****************/

        if ($course) {
            // If $course is an integer, it is a course id, get the object from database.
            if (is_int($course) || is_string($course)) {
                if (!$course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $course), '*', MUST_EXIST)) {
                    print_error('Course ID was incorrect');
                }
            }
        }
        echo "Course List";
        print_object($course);
    }
    echo "course Receiving";
    print_object($course);
    return $course;
}
```

This code returns only one value. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently overwriting the `$course`-variable a couple of times on each iteration. That's why you only get one (the last) value.

We need to make sure that we push the courses to an array instead of overwriting the same variable.
Something like this:

```
// Define the array that will keep all our courses
$courses = [];

// Define an array that will keep all the names
$names = ['fullname' => []];

foreach($enrolledusercourses as $key =>$value){ 
    // Save the ID to a temporary variable
    $id = $enrolledusercourses[$key]->id;

    if ($id) {
        // This is also a temporary variable. ($course vs $courses)
        $course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $id), '*', MUST_EXIST);

        if ($course) {
            // We found a course, let's add it to the courses array
            $courses[] = $course;

            // Add the name to your names array
            $names['fullname'][] = $course->fullname;
        }
    }
}

// Now we have an array (the new $courses variable) that will contain all the courses.

// Implode the names
$names['fullname'] = implode(', ', $names['fullname']);
// Convert it to an object
$names = (object)$names;

echo "course Receiving";
print_object($courses);
return $courses;
```

The above will give you an array with all the courses and an object with all the names comma separated.

Comment: Are you printing and returning `$course` or `$courses`? You need to make sure you're using the correct variable in the correct place.

Comment: Edit your question to include your updated code (keep the old, just add the new code) so I can see what's going on. If the old code gave you a result, this should as well.